# x86 intrinsic select from 2 values

Tags: windows, x86, intel, intrinsics

I have written a Mandelbrot generator that uses x86 intrinsics depending on which are available on the host machine. It uses 32-bit floats or 64-bit doubles depending on how zoomed in the current view is. I want to be able to use x86 intrinsics to select which value to copy from based on a given mask. For example this (in very simplified form)

```
Mask: 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
Val1: 5.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
Val2: 0.0f, 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f

Out:  5.3f, 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f
```

In AVX2 using floats, I thought the following would work but it doesn't. It compiles but my output is not as I desire.

```cpp
Tmp1 = _mm256_andnot_ps(Val1, Mask);
Tmp2 = _mm256_and_ps(Val2, Mask);
Out = _mm256_or_ps(Tmp1, Tmp2);
```

full godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/jjGsc6edn

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you [edit] your code to be a [mre]? What are the types of `Val1`, `Mask`, etc? Does `Mask` actually contain 4 times `int32(0xff)` or `int32(-1)`? By "it doesn't work", do you mean it does not compile, or does it give unexpected results?

Comment: If your registers contain just four values each (i.e., `__m128`), you should use `_mm_andnot_ps(mask, val1)`, etc (note that for andnot the `mask` needs to be the first argument, for and/or the order does not matter). Alternatively, you can use `_mm_blendv_ps(Val1, Val2, Mask)` (assuming the types are correct and `Mask` actually has the highest bit set where required).

Comment: I updated the original question to include a godbolt link and describe that it compiles but doesn't give me the desired output

Comment: As I said in my second comment, you need to switch the argument order for `andnot_ps`. Also, in your godbolt-link you use `set_ps` for `Val1, Val2` but `set_epi32` for the mask -- use `setr_epi32` here as well: https://godbolt.org/z/b65Pxnf7f (slightly modified to make it compile/execute with gcc instead of msvc).

Comment: Great, thank you! So my main issue seemed to be that the mask ordering is important for andnot_ps.